# Async Recursion with JavaScript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

This is probably a noob JavaScript question, but I'm looking to know if my solution to a problem I am having is 'correct'

I have created the following sample application that recreates my error:

Firstly in index.js

```
var processor = require('./fileProcessor/processor.js');

var container = {
    source: "source.txt",
    destination: "destination.txt"
};

new processor().process(container);
```

I create my container object which has the name of the source file and the name of the destination file. This is passed into the process function of the processor:

```
var fileProcessor = require('./fileProcessor.js');

module.exports = function Processor() {

  this.process = function(container) {
    var file = new fileProcessor();

    if(container.finished === undefined) {

      if(container.body === undefined) {
        file.read(container, this.process);
      } else {
        file.write(container, this.process);
      }

    }

  };

};
```

As you can see this calls the read and write functions passing in the container and the process function as the callback, the fileProcessor looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function() {

  this.read = function(container,  callback) {

    fs.readFile(container.source, function (err, data) {

      if(err) throw err;

      container.body = data;

      callback(container);

    });

  };

  this.write = function(container, callback) {

    fs.writeFile(container.destination, container.body, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        container.finished = true;

        callback(container);
    });

  };

};
```

In simple terms the processor calls file.read, which reads the file and calls back into the process function, which then calls the write function. However at the end of the write function an error is thrown:

```
    callback(container);
    ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Obviously when passing in `this.process` to `file.write(container, this.process);` the `this` isn't the `this` I intend it to be!

If I update my processor by adding a `processFunction` variable:

```
var fileProcessor = require('./fileProcessor.js');

module.exports = function Processor() {

  var processFunction = function(container) {
    var file = new fileProcessor();

    if(container.finished === undefined) {

      if(container.body === undefined) {
        file.read(container, processFunction);
      } else {
        file.write(container, processFunction);
      }

    }
  };

  this.process = function(container) {
     processFunction(container);
  };

};
```

Everything works fine. Is this a good way to do this or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a fine way to do it. There is one possible modification that you might make. Since you are creating a new name in your scope just for the purpose of recursing, you could just name your function and refer to it by its name inside of the function.

```
module.exports = function Processor() {

  this.process = function processFunction(container) {
    var file = new fileProcessor();

    if(container.finished === undefined) {

      if(container.body === undefined) {
        file.read(container, processFunction);
      } else {
        file.write(container, processFunction);
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Then you can avoid creating a name (`processFunction`) that will be visible outside the function.

Take a look here for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression

Comment: Naming the function is a lot neater, thanks for the tip!